# Property of absolute convergent serie

Tags: real-analysis

So I just ran into this inequality for absolutely convergent series:
$$|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k | \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k| $$
I cant seem to find the proof of this inequality, is it available somewhere?

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality to partial sums and take limits.  If I'm not mistaken, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Work on your subscripts please.

Comment: This is just a generalization of the fact that $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Ok, so should I apply that to the left side or right side of the inequality?

Comment: @zhw. What do you mean with subscripts? Im new to this page sorry..

Comment: @T.Bongers Okay but is the triangle-inequality connected to the proof?

Comment: The statement $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$ **is** the triangle inequality.

Comment: @T.Bongers Yeah, but I dont see how you apply it to the proof..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is shorthand for $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$.  For each $k$,
$$
    | a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k | \leq |a_1| + |a_2| + \dots + |a_k|
$$
(that is the triangle inequality).  Since both $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converge, we can take the limit of each side of the above inequality and arrive at 
$$
    \left|\lim_{k\to\infty}(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k)\right|
\leq \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(|a_1| + |a_2| + \dots + |a_k|\right)
$$
which is what we want.

Comment: Okay thanks.. But could you explain why you say "since both converge, we can take the limit". So if we didnt knew that they both converged, we couldnt take the limit, or?

Comment: @fejz1234: That's right.  If the series did not converge, we could not take the limit of both sides (since said limits do not exist).